# How To Replicate This User Interface Design?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, user-interface

I want to create a UI like the on in Mint.com app.  Is it a UIScrollView with UITableView cells in it?

Notice how each block/cell has multiple data values in it.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a `UITableView` with `UITableViewStyleGrouped` and multiple sections. The spacing between sections appears to be increased from the default value.

The cell backgrounds have a slight gradient added to give them depth. Each section appears to have a different custom layout of labels, and, in the one case, a custom slider-like object. The object on the right is a standard `UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton`.

You can achieve similar effects by subclassing `UITableViewCell`.

Comment: Thanks PengOne.  So is each cell in the pic created separately, with UILabels and stuff? Also, how do you set the row height differently for different sections

Comment: @Jon: The cells in a given section appear to use the same custom `UITableViewCell`, but each section appears to have it's own custom subclass. Use `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` to set the height individually or per section.

Answer (score 7):

This is all about customising the table view and table view cells. The best tutorial I've found is [Cocoa with Love: Easy custom UITableView drawing](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html). It's a good place to start.